# swapping the first and last element in a stack using c++

Tags: arrays, stack, swap

i want to make a function to take a stack (as array)
and for it to return the stack swapping the first element with the last element in the Stack
so i'll use a temp stack for the data
and i'll use 
but how will i know when will i reach the end of the stack ?

i've wrote the implementation of stack as an array 
but i need help with the function swap

```
void Swap(Stack x)
{
Stack tmp(100);
int top1 = x.pop;

for (int i = 0;; i++)
{
x.pop = tmp.push;
}

}
```

i know its wrong but i'm not sure 
any help would be appreciated 
,thanks 
Edit
i wrote the function at first this way and found i can't take the parameters

```
void stack::Swap()
{
Stack tmp(100);
int top1 =  this->pop;

for (int i = 0;; i++)
{
this->pop = tmp.push
}

};
```

Edit here is a code from an answer

```
Stack Swap(Stack x){

int mytop,mybottom;

mytop=x.pop();

int tmp[x.length-2],i=0;

while(!x.isEmpty()){

    mybottom=x.pop();

    tmp[i++]=mybottom;


    }

Stack returnIt;

returnIt.push(mytop);

for(i=0;i<=x.length -3;i++){

    returnIt.push(tmp[i]);

    }

returnIt.push(mybottom);

return returnIt;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IDEA** : Store top and bottom of stack in a variable and elements between top and bottom in an array. Now you just push bottom of original stack into new stack and than elements in original order and than finally the top of original stack.

[code](http://ideone.com/fIBAaT).

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void rev(stack<int>&x){
    int sz=x.size(),mytop,mybottom;
    mytop=x.top();
    x.pop();
    int tmp[sz-1],i=0;
    while(!x.empty()){
        mybottom=x.top();
        tmp[i++]=mybottom;
        x.pop();
        } 
    stack<int> returnIt;
    returnIt.push(mybottom);
    for(i=0;i<=sz-3;i++){
        returnIt.push(tmp[i]);
        }
    returnIt.push(mytop);
    while(!returnIt.empty()){
        int tt=returnIt.top();
        x.push(tt);
        returnIt.pop();
    }
    }
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    stack<int>x;
    x.push(1);
    x.push(2);
    x.push(3);
    x.push(4);
    x.push(5);
    stack<int>y=x;
    cout<<"Before reversing : ";
    while(!y.empty()){
        int tt=y.top();
        cout<<tt;
        y.pop();
    }

    rev(x);
    cout<<"\nAfter reversing : ";
    while(!x.empty()){
        cout<<x.top();
        x.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i understood what you did but the function should be a void
so the function should do the following
if the stack was 1 2 3 4 5 
it should become 5 2 3 4 1
and so on
for (size) it's called length in the code i wrote and it was a private parameter ,so i changed it to public
and length is a variable from the user to enter

Comment: oops i returned 'stack' from a void function(thats wrong) but anyways you can pass stack as reference and than at last copy contents of 'returnIt' to original stack ie. 'x'

Comment: yes i did that but the problem is that the whole stack was in reverse

Comment: it worked ! thank you i understood it but the trick is to make the main implementation of the stack
here is my full code 
can you help me finding the problem ?
http://ideone.com/4aQRKO (link)

Comment: there you go.. [link](http://ideone.com/DZUrsC) @AymanIBreak run it on local machine or if u are using 'ideone' don't forget to provide input..

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i really understood your question correctly but it looks like you want the first element of a stack to be the last and the last to be the first. If so, you havent really understood the way how a stack works and when to use it, because a stack is like a stack in real life. For example you go a stack of Pringles (yes the potato chips) in one of the classic cylinders. Now a stack allows you just to access the element on top of the stack (the last object that were added), thats because the stack will crash if you try to take out one of the center. But if you want to get a element in the center you have to take so much elements from the top till you reached that element, but if you doing something like that, you are using a stack wrong! A stack is to collect Objects in order they were added (like a list) but just with access to the top. You can use this for example for a undo function in an editor, there you add all the actions you did onto a stack. Now if you use the undo function, one after the next action can be undone, but if you now do a different action, theres a new element on top of the stack and these you have taken of cant be placed on that again, so they are just broken (You can eat them if you want) (like a time paradoxon: "You cant undo something you havent done and you cant redo something you will never have done").

I hope i helped you understanding the basic job of a stack, but if you have any other question or I miss understood your question, correct me.

But if you really want to do, what you are trying, you have to think about, how you could do something like that in reallife: You have to take every element from the stack, one by one, and then build a new stack with the same order in the middle, but the first index you put on the stack is the first from the old stack.

I never really programmed in C++, but in pseudo code it could look like this:

```
Stack stack;
List<StackElement> list;
//Converting stack to list for better access
for(int i = 0; i<stack.size;i++)
{
    list.add(stack.top);
    stack.pop;
}
//Add the last element from the list (the last from the stack) on top of the stack (thats now the only object in the stack)
stack.push(list.get(list.size()-1));
list.remove(list.size()-1); //Remove this element
//Save our last element
StackElement lastElement = list.get(0);
list.remove(0);
//Inserting the mid
for(int i = 0; i<list.size;i++)
{
    stack.push(list.get(i));
}
//Now put the last element from the old stack on top of the new
stack.push(lastElement):
```

I am sorry for my bad english, I hope you understood the basic thing i wanted to say. And the code is just theory, it can be wrong!

Comment: i understand the stack and that's what i'm asking for
if i want a stack to be changed from 1 2 3 4 5 to 5 2 3 4 1
using a function 
i should pop all the stack to get to the last element 
and i want it to be a void not to return the modified stack

Comment: Whats the problem about returning? And you dont have to do it, you could also do what the pseudo code says directly with the Stack...

Comment: this problem is to be solved as a stack to use an other stack
the main idea i guess
1 store the top element
2-put the middle of the original stack in an other stack
3-store the last element
4 return the first element to the stack
5- return the middle then return the last element to the top
but i need help in writing the function

Comment: Sorry, I still dont get it. You want to use multiple stacks? Or what? I could rewrite my pseudo code into a real funtion if you want, theres not the problem.

Comment: i'm so sorry but i'm not sure what pseudo code is :(
i only took c++ for now
and no i only want a function which takes a stack as a parameter and modify the stack (swap the first and last element)
like the edited code

Comment: Pseudo Code means code that isnt really executeable, but when you read it, you now what the code does. I will edit my post and try to translate into a c++ function, but as i told before, i am not a C++ programmer!

Comment: oh i'm so sorry yes thats the way it should be done ,if you can write it in c++ it'd be great