# swapping first and last element in stack c++ using stl

Tags: c++, stack

i created an account so i can get some help with stacks in STL , i need to write a function that takes stack as a parameter and swaps the first element with the last element , i searched the site for some help i found one :"https://stackoverflow.com/a/36188943/9990214" , i tried the same thing , but i keep getting this error : expression must have a constant value with red line under "int tmp[sz-1];".
it keeps giving me the error before reaching the main , any help would be appreciated , keep in mind am trying to write the function using STL.
ps : i tried replying with a comment to the person who answered the question but it's not allowing me to do that because i need 50 reputation.

```
using namespace std;
void rev(stack<int>&x){
    int sz=x.size(),mytop,mybottom;
    mytop=x.top();
    x.pop();
    int tmp[sz-1],i=0;
    while(!x.empty()){
        mybottom=x.top();
        tmp[i++]=mybottom;
        x.pop();
    } 
    stack<int> returnIt;
    returnIt.push(mybottom);
    for(i=0;i<=sz-3;i++){
        returnIt.push(tmp[i]);
    }
    returnIt.push(mytop);
    while(!returnIt.empty()){
        int tt=returnIt.top();
        x.push(tt);
        returnIt.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste the code in anyways, if you can, and we'll format it for you. We can't help you without a proper [mcve].

Comment: i put it in the bottom , there you go.

Comment: Is it mandatory to implement your stack as a [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)?  Its default, underlying type [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) exposes more flexibility in its raw form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is that variable-length arrays are not a part of standard C++. This matters for your definition of `tmp`:

```
int tmp[sz-1], i=0; //sz is not known at compile-time, therefore, this is invalid code
```

Some compilers will allow code like this by allowing VLA's, but not being standard, you should use a different solution. Usually, for tasks like this, `std::vector` is ideal:

```
std::vector<int> tmp(sz - 1);
int i = 0;
```

This should compile (so long as you `#include<vector>` alongside your other includes), and should have the behavior you expect from your code.

Comment: thanks for the help , everything works now  , so it seems the problem is from my compiler?

Comment: @pi.ras Calling the problem the "compiler" is misleading, in my estimation. You shouldn't expect any compiler to allow the construction you tried to use. Some will, but VLAs are non-standard, and (as a consequence) not universally supported.